# how to create a column with the index of the biggest among other columns AND some condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, dataset

I have a dataset with some columns, I want to create another column, where values are the column name of the variable with the highest value **BUT different from 1**

For Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 0.2, 0.1, 0],
                    'B': [0.2,1, 0, 0.5],
                    'C': [1, 0.4, 0.3, 1]},
                   index=['1', '2', '3', '4'])
df
```

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0 | 0.2 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 0.2 | 1.0 | 0.4 |
| 3 | 0.1 | 0.0 | 0.3 |
| 4 | 0.0 | 0.5 | 1.0 |

Should give an output like

| index | A | B | C | NEWCOL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.0 | 0.2 | 1.0 | B |
| 2 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.1 | C |
| 3 | 0.1 | 0.4 | 0.2 | B |
| 4 | 0.0 | 0.5 | 1.0 | B |

```
df2['newcol'] = df2.idxmax(axis=1) if df2.max(index=1) != 1
```

but didn't work

Comment: added an answer, does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# filter out the data that is 1 and find the id of the max value using idxmax
df['newcol']=df[~df.isin([1])].idxmax(axis=1)
df
```

```
      A       B     C   newcol
1   1.0     0.2     1.0     B
2   0.2     1.0     0.4     C
3   0.1     0.0     0.3     C
4   0.0     0.5     1.0     B
```

**PS:** your input, starting and expected data don't match. The above is based on the input DF